# Control-capslock Tmux error?

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard-layout, tmux

I'm having trouble getting `tmux` to accept a caps-lock key that has been remapped using `setxkbmap`. I use the following:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

When running `tmux`, the usual BASH command line editing is fine with this "new" control key (the old caps lock button) -- works for moving cursor forward/backward, previous commands, etc. However, the `tmux` prefix key combination will not accept this new key, if I try to use the "new" ctrl button while running `tmux`, I am unable to call the prefix, making `tmux` unusable.

I am running ubuntu 14.04, `gnome-terminal`, and `tmux` version 1.8. I have also tried using the `gnome-tweak-tool` to change the caps lock to ctrl, and using `setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps` also.

Neither improves the situation. Oddly, when swapping keys the "new" capslock (old ctrl) is acknowledged by `tmux`, all of the following text is capitalized.

If this seems like an inappropriate place for this question let me know, I'll place it on tmux github issues. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, without really knowing the mechanism behind this error, I fixed the problems by resetting the caps lock, then changing it back to ctrl:  `setxkbmap -option`  then:  `setxkbmap -option caps:ctrl_modifier`  Now tmux likes my setup.

Comment: Or not. This solution is not stable. For what ever reason, this correction lasts for an indeterminate amount of time then reverts to my original problem. I'm at a loss.